# Strange numpy loadtxt behaviour: not reading 2nd column properly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm using the following code to read from the following simple tab-separated text file

```
0   2   30
0   0   30
1   0   20
2   0   30
3   0   10
4   0   30
4   2   30
```

`import numpy as np 
x_z_ks=np.loadtxt(fname = r"C:\Users\david\Engelund_input\sezione_rettangolare.dat", delimiter='\t')`

It seems as if the code has problems reading specifically the second column. Printing the matrix gives the following results. Somehow the first value of the second column changes position inside the column?

```
print(x_z_ks)

[[ 0.  0. 30.]
 [ 0.  0. 30.]
 [ 1.  0. 20.]
 [ 2.  0. 30.]
 [ 3.  0. 10.]
 [ 4.  2. 30.]
 [ 4.  2. 30.]]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't want to download your file, especially if it expects some sort of registration.  Show a sample as text if you want help.  The array print looks normal to me.

Comment: Thank hpaulj for your efforts, I've found the issue. there were erroneous code lines that followed.